# How to Create a JSP Page Table And Record Actions

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am bit green on JSP/JSTL so I need a little bit of help. I have a web page design that looks like

======================================================
=  Name  SSN  Address                                =
=                                                    =
=                                                    =
=                                     Add Row        =
======================================================

As user clicks on "Add Row", a new row is added to the table. The user types in some stuff and then, clicks on Add Row. The examples shown to me, uses scriptlets "code over here is really old". I would like to use JSTL foreach construct and iterate over the construct. After the list is rendered, how do I store the values user typed into the element I have ? Foreach construct seems only good for rendering or am I mistaken. Any tutorials or examples...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, I have been downvoted even though I have researched the question before asking this. Simple answer is this, you can not. However there are two solutions; I came up with two in my head;

-- your table is static for the entered records. U can simply loop over the beans and display what's entered and give them a button to remove a row if they want to. The last row is dynamic and has the input tags.

-- you rewrite the ids of each input element such as  name1, ssn1, address1, name2, ssn2, address2 for row 2. This gives the user to update any field on any row they want. However it is butt ugly in my opinion and I like the first solution so I will go ahead with the first solution I have in mind....

Comment: Maybe because you didn't ask a concrete programming question, but instead asked for tutorials/examples on a too broad subject. Stackoverflow.com as being a Q&A site isn't the right place for this, you should instead look for a chatbox or discussion forum. This is surely possible btw.

Comment: Thanks but I could not find a concrete example for my problem. Examples found are way too simplistic... Checked the questions on stackoverflow and jsp faqs as well. I was asking more of, is this possible and how the design should be ?